# Mongoose distinct select but whole object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Mongoose in Node.js. I have this model structure in MongoDB:

```
{
   "_id":"5ac17dc27707e91ed00cea7d",
   "appid":123,
   "name":"Stellaris",
   "code":"xxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I need to select all items BUT when there is more items of same appid, select just ONE or each appid. Distinct return just array of one field. How select whole objects instead where items with same appid are only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '$appid',
        "docs": {
            $first: {
                "name": "$name",
                "code": "$code"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

**OR**  If you don't want docs field.

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '$appid',
        "name": {
            $first: "$name"
        },
        "code": {
            $first: "$code"
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Very nice. Thats it! Thanks!

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks @Rahul Sharma

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, in mongo db no duplicate object store. as it generates random id. if you want to get internal object then you can use distinct https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Otherwise you can do below steps.

1. Get all data from collection as array.
2. use lodash for find duplicat. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniq
3. you need to install it in your nodejs project

   npm i --save lodash

Then use

```
var _ = require('lodash');
```

and use

```
_.uniq(Your Array);
```

Comment: Lodash is my Plan B, but I was believing I can do this natively by MongoDB to save some bandwidth

Comment: yes you are correct. then you can check for distinct().

Comment: @RahulSharma got it natively :)